# Generating a unordered list hash from a array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to use hashes to generate an unordered list that i can further use in a jstree. But this array has to be generated only from an array that has been passed thru .

```
my @array = ( "New Order","Recurring Order","Previously Cancelled Order");
```

I want the output to look something like

```
$data = {
         "New Order" => {
                         "Recurring Order" =>{
                                              Previously cancelled Order = 1
                                             }
                        }
    };
```

I can simply do

```
my $data{$array[0]}{$array[1]}{$array[2]} = 1
```

but the array can be of n variables, so it becomes a bit more complicated than that. I am thinking of recursion, but i have been sitting here for the last hour trying to figure that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will generate the data structure as you have defined it.  Not sure why you'd want it though.

```
my @input = ( "New Order","Recurring Order","Previously Cancelled Order");

my $data = 1;
$data = {$_ => $data} for reverse @input;

use Data::Dump;
dd $data;
```

If you're just wanting to randomize your array, then use [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html);

```
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my @newOrder = shuffle @input;
```

Comment: This is just the perfect solution. I just needed it because there is a complicated database query that needs to be simplified using the array as list of columns and each incremental array element is the level of the jstree i have to make with that data . 

thanks this is perfect .

Answer (score 1):

```
sub recursive {
  my $v = shift @_;
  return @_>1 ? { $v => recursive(@_) } : { $v => @_ };
}

my @array = ( "New Order","Recurring Order","Previously Cancelled Order");
use Data::Dumper; print Dumper recursive(@array, 1);
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'New Order' => {
                       'Recurring Order' => {
                                              'Previously Cancelled Order' => 1
                                            }
                     }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you . That was really helpful. Totally sorted my problem out